# Struggling to get FACEBOOK LIKE button to work on site "developed" using Iweb on a MAC

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, iweb

I have tried some of the older responses already posted on the site, but am still struggling to get the code to work.

I have developed a site using iweb, its basic - I am no coder, www.ondulinetileeffectroofingsheets.com , i have easily managed to insert a working video from youtube, and thought that simply copying and inserting the HTML snippet for the facebook like button would also work but the image fails to work, so when I copy and paste the from the facebook developers site, the Facebook image doesn't not appear. - any ideas - thanks in advance x ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to take a look at this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
In there there are details of how to implement `og:tags` on your page.  These tags help the Facebook to decide what image, text and links will be taken from your page to be displayed in the "like" dialog.
The tags look something like this :

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="YOUR_NAMESPACE:recipe" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/zhen/cookie.html">
```